# android save duplicate ringtones save

Tags: java, android

aim trying to transfer ringtone from my app to user sdcard every thing works good

but when i try to save another ringtone the function save the old ringtones and the new as the same mp3 file

like first time i save lol.mp3 its work when i save another one like hora.mp3

its save mora.mp3 and lol.mp3 as same file of hora.mp3 how to fix this issue !

```
public boolean saveas(int ressound , String ringname , Boolean isringtone , Boolean isnotificatoion  ){

        byte[] buffer=null;
        InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
        int size=0;

        try {
        size = fIn.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        fIn.read(buffer);
        fIn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return false;
        }

        String path="/sdcard/Islamyat/";
        String filename="mysound"+".mp3";

        boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
        if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

        FileOutputStream save;
        try {
        save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
        save.write(buffer);
        save.flush();
        save.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return false;
        }

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

        File k = new File(path, filename);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, ringname);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "yappname");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, isringtone);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, isnotificatoion);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        //Insert it into the database
        Uri newUri= this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
        this,
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
        newUri
        );
        return true;
        }
```

Comment: `String filename="mysound"+".mp3";`  Huh?

Comment: should i change it to (ringname) ? is this will resolve my issue ?